# Updating D3 data doesn't remove old data from faux-3d example

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am working on extending the example found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/4973620). I have a data source that will pull in data for different periods of time. The data is as expected and draws well individually. I added a timer to iterate through the result set. The following code is in the original example. There are three calls points, flyers, arcLines (only flyers is shown below)

```
svg.append("g").attr("class","flyers")
 .selectAll("path").data(links)
 .enter().append("path")
 .attr("class","flyer")
 .attr("d", function(d) { return swoosh(flying_arc(d)) })
```

I changed the code to this to allow updates and they kind of work. The lines/points/flyers are removed and only the data from the time interval are displayed.

```
var flyer_data = svg_flyers
        .selectAll("path").data(links);

    flyer_data
        .exit().remove();

    flyer_data
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "flyer")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return swoosh(flying_arc(d))
        });
```

Now the data isn't displayed correctly when the points and lines are supposedly in focus. Only data that is right on the horizon is displayed before its clipped. There is another side effect of the above code. The bound data structure is changed correctly but the SVG gets more and more points/lines/arcs which are not displayed. This last observation is particular baffling with the ever growing SVG definitions. It slows down the browser after a few minutes.

I have created a gist with enough code to demonstrate the issue. The Gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mobsniuk/abdba60f6658f04409e6).

Comment: Where did you add `.exit().remove()`? The link to your gist isn't working for me.

Comment: I've updated the link (added gist incorrectly the first time). I have two versions of the code one with the original failings and an "improved" version. The data is sort of updated the lines and points change completely with each time step. Problem is it isn't displayed correctly. You have to rotate the globe to see the lines and points as they fade away. The data in the SVG.g points/arcs/flyers do not prune data out from it. This is even more baffling then before.

Answer (score 0):

Your link to gist isn't working.

However, depending on your situation you can select your object (in this case your path) by class or id. In the example I've provided you can give your path an id and refer to it.

```
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
             { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
             { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

var lineData2 = [ { "x": 5,   "y": 1},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
             { "x": 10,  "y": 40}, { "x": 40,  "y": 60},
             { "x": 5,  "y": 80},  { "x": 60, "y": 100}];

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return d.x; })
.y(function(d) { return d.y; })
.interpolate("linear");

 d3.select("svg")
 .append("path")
 .attr("id", "MyUniqueId")
 .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData));

 d3.select("#MyUniqueId")
 .transition()
 .duration(5000)
 .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData2));
```

See js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3M54q/3/